# TypeScript: add more data to enum

Tags: java, typescript, enums

In TypeScript, is it possible to add more stuff (properties, methods, etc.) to enum constants, like in Java?

Java example demonstrating adding of fields, methods and constructor:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not using an enum, but you can get the same exact thing using a class and a few static members:

```
class Planet {
    public static MERCURY = new Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6);
    public static VENUS = new Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6);
    public static EARTH = new Planet(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6);
    public static MARS = new Planet(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6);
    public static JUPITER = new Planet(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7);
    public static SATURN = new Planet(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7);
    public static URANUS = new Planet(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7);
    public static NEPTUNE = new Planet(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);
    
    private mass: number;
    private radius: number;

    private constructor(mass: number, radius: number) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public static G = 6.67300E-11;

    public surfaceGravity(): number {
        return Planet.G * this.mass / (this.radius * this.radius);
    }

    public surfaceWeight(otherMass: number) {
        return otherMass * this.surfaceGravity();
    }
}

console.log(Planet.MERCURY.surfaceGravity());
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Planet%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20MERCURY%20%3D%20new%20Planet(3.303e%2B23%2C%202.4397e6)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20VENUS%20%3D%20new%20Planet(4.869e%2B24%2C%206.0518e6)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20EARTH%20%3D%20new%20Planet(5.976e%2B24%2C%206.37814e6)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20MARS%20%3D%20new%20Planet(6.421e%2B23%2C%203.3972e6)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20JUPITER%20%3D%20new%20Planet(1.9e%2B27%2C%207.1492e7)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20SATURN%20%3D%20new%20Planet(5.688e%2B26%2C%206.0268e7)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20URANUS%20%3D%20new%20Planet(8.686e%2B25%2C%202.5559e7)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20NEPTUNE%20%3D%20new%20Planet(1.024e%2B26%2C%202.4746e7)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20mass%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20radius%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20constructor(mass%3A%20number%2C%20radius%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.mass%20%3D%20mass%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.radius%20%3D%20radius%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20G%20%3D%206.67300E-11%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20surfaceGravity()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Planet.G%20*%20this.mass%20%2F%20(this.radius%20*%20this.radius)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20surfaceWeight(otherMass%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20otherMass%20*%20this.surfaceGravity()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(Planet.MERCURY.surfaceGravity())%3B))

In java for each item in the enum a static instance is created, which means that this indeed does the same thing, it's just that java has a nicer syntax for defining enums.

---

#### Edit

Here's a version with the equivalent `Planet.values()` which java will generate:

```
class Planet {
    private static VALUES: Planet[] = [];

    public static MERCURY = new Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6);
    public static VENUS = new Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6);
    ...
    
    private mass: number;
    private radius: number;

    private constructor(mass: number, radius: number) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;

        Planet.VALUES.push(this);
    }

    public static values() {
        return Planet.VALUES;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

---

#### 2nd edit

Here's a way to implement the `valueOf`:

```
   public static valueOf(name: string): Planet | null {
        const names = Object.keys(this);
        for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (this[names[i]] instanceof Planet && name.toLowerCase() === names[i].toLowerCase()) {
                return this[names[i]];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. Probably will choose this answer as accepted. Should we also protect from creation of arbitrary instances, via something like private constructor?

Comment: Indeed. Great! Sorry I did not notice. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted the answer. Thanks again. Any other "protections"/features (like priv ctor) need to be done? Like in pre 1.5 java? Like toString, equals, hashCode?

Comment: Query by value? List all members?

Comment: That's up to you and what you require from your "enums". Check my revised answer I added the `Planet.values()` method like you get in java.

Comment: Thanks. And best way to get a value given its name as string? Like `MyEnum.valueOf("SOME_VAL")` in Java.

Comment: Added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't it be good to make it more like a dictionary? E.g. `private static VALUES: { [id: string]: MyEnum; } = {}` A bit faster lookup perhaps?

Comment: If you're using the `VALUE` property then yeah. But I would use a `Map<string, MyEnum>` instead of `{ [id: string]: MyEnum; }`

Comment: VALUES is not safe from modification from outside, or is it?
`Planet.values().push(Planet.VENUS)`

Comment: @schrobe the `VALUES` member is private so using typescript you can't change it (with js at runtime you obviously can). but with `Planet.values()` you can. You can return a clone of the values: `return Planet.VALUES.slice(0);` or you can even use an immutable array instead of a regular one.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be adequate as we want it to behave the same as the Java solution. Not preventing the modification allows for surprising side-effects. Using `slice(0)` here seems right!

Comment: Smart. In my case the initialization of the 'VALUES' has to be done before any 'new Planet', otherwise I have a 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')' when doing 'Planet.VALUES.push(this)'. Seems obvious, so I am surprised no one mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible. You can just assign property names

> See this reference for the TypeScript spec https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/30cb20434a6b117e007a4959b2a7c16489f86069/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#a7-enums

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 'same thing' using a const.

Obviously this solution isn't exactly like enumerations, it's just a different use of the keys of a const object instead of an actual enumeration value.

```js
export const OrderStateEnum = {
    WAITING_SCORING: { key: 1, value: "WAITING for SCORING" },
    WAITING_ACCEPTANCE: { key: 2, value: "Waiting for acceptance" },
    ORDER_ACCEPTED: { key: 3, value: "Order accepted" },
 } as const

export type OrderStateEnum = keyof typeof OrderStateEnum

export function valueOf(value: string): OrderStateEnum{
    for(var key in OrderStateEnum) {
        if(value.toLowerCase()=== OrderStateEnum[key].value.toLowerCase()){
            return OrderStateEnum[key];
        }
    }
}
```

To receive all the values of the false enum:

```js
  states = OrderStateEnum;
```

To receive a certain value of the false enum:

```js
  OrderStateEnum.WAITING_SCORING.value;
```

Below is a usage via *ngFor

```js
<select formControlName="statoOrdine" [(ngModel)]="stato">
    <option *ngFor="let item of states | keyvalue" [value]="item.value.key"> 
      {{item.value.value}}</option>
</select>
```